# Does "charge density" account for all charges, or only negative charges, and do opposite charges cancel each other or add?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, charge, conductors, metals

if I had 10 electrons and 8 protons in a meter cubed would the charge density be 2 or 10 or 18? I suspect 10, but  I don't see why charge density only takes into account the negative charges.

another way of putting it.  if I polarize a metal stick, such that charge density on the left =  x. the charge density on the right =?
again I suspect 0 rather than negative x

Answer (score 2):

> if I had 10 electrons and 8 protons in a meter cubed would the charge density be 2 or 10 or 18?

It would be 2; or more exactly, it would be $-2\;\mathrm{e/m^3}$.

Charge density does not account only for electrons. It accounts for all the charges, positive or negative, and positive and negative charges count opposite, so that charge density is zero in neutral objects.

Comment: so when I read in a textbook something like "a cube of metal has a charge density of x *10 ^15 electrons per cm" ... they mean x*10^15 free electrons per cm

Comment: I presume so, yes.